# View doesn't get updated after the model changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I have this UI defined below. Everything works fine except the reset button changes the model but it doesn't update the view. If I go over one of the text fields the view gets updated instantly.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @StateObject private var _model = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach($_model.Vars) { v in
                Section(v.Caption.wrappedValue) {
                    TextField(v.Caption.wrappedValue, text: v.Text)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
            }
            
            Button("Save") {
                for v in _model.Vars {
                    if !v.Read()
                    {
                        showAlert = true
                        return
                    }
                }
                
                let db = Global.Database
                var settings = db.Settings
                db.Update
                {
                    for v in _model.Vars {
                        v.Write(&settings)
                    }
                }
                
                dismiss()
            }
            .alert("Invalid numbers", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Button("OK") { showAlert = false }
            }
            
            Button("Reset") {
                Update(RealmSettings())
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            Update(Global.Database.Settings)
        }
    }
    
    private func Update(_ settings: RealmSettings)
    {
        for v in _model.Vars {
            v.Update(settings)
        }
    }
    
    class ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        @Published var Vars: [VarBase] = [
            FloatVar("Rotation Threshold", \.RotationThreshold),
            FloatVar("Eye Openness Threshold", \.EyeOpennessThreshold),
            IntVar("Capture Sample Count", \.CaptureSampleCount),
            IntVar("Lip Distance Threshold (mm)", \.LipDistanceThreshold_mm),
            FloatVar("Camera Move Threshold (mm)", \.CameraMoveThreshold_mm),
            FloatVar("Camera Rotation Threshold (deg)", \.CameraRotationThreshold_deg)
        ]
    }
    
    class VarBase : ObservableObject, Identifiable
    {
        let id = UUID()
        
        @Published var Text = ""
        var Caption: String
        
        init(_ caption: String) { Caption = caption }
        
        func Read() -> Bool { fatalError("Abstract Method") }
        func Update(_ settings: RealmSettings) { fatalError("Abstract Method") }
        func Write(_ settings: inout RealmSettings) { fatalError("Abstract Method") }
    }
    
    class Var<T> : VarBase
    {
        private var _value: T
        private let _parser: (String) -> T?
        private let _toString: (T) -> String
        private let _keyPath: WritableKeyPath<RealmSettings, T>

        init(
            _ value: T,
            _ caption: String,
            _ parser: @escaping (String) -> T?,
            _ toString: @escaping (T) -> String,
            _ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<RealmSettings, T>)
        {
            _value = value
            _parser = parser
            _toString = toString
            _keyPath = keyPath
            super.init(caption)
        }
        
        override func Read() -> Bool
        {
            guard let value = _parser(Text) else { return false }
            _value = value
            return true
        }
        
        override func Write(_ settings: inout RealmSettings)
        {
            settings[keyPath: _keyPath] = _value
        }
        
        override func Update(_ settings: RealmSettings)
        {
            Text = _toString(settings[keyPath: _keyPath])
        }
    }
    
    class IntVar : Var<Int>
    {
        init(_ caption: String, _ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<RealmSettings, Int>)
        {
            super.init(0, caption, { s in Int(s) }, { v in String(v) }, keyPath)
        }
    }
    
    class FloatVar : Var<Float>
    {
        init(_ caption: String, _ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<RealmSettings, Float>)
        {
            super.init(0, caption, { s in Float(s) }, { v in String(v) }, keyPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Published doesn’t work with classes like you’re doing (without some manual work at least). Change your models to structs. Otherwise, you’ll have to call objectWillChange by hand when you update.

Comment: Functions and properties should start with a lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, changing the code as below solves the issue.

###### Old

```swift
ForEach($_model.Vars) { v in
    Section(v.Caption.wrappedValue) {
        TextField(v.Caption.wrappedValue, text: v.Text)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
    }
}
```

###### New

```swift
ForEach(_model.Vars) { v in
    VarView(Var: v)
}

// Introducing a new view
struct VarView : View
{
    @StateObject var Var: VarBase
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Section(Var.Caption) {
            TextField(Var.Caption, text: $Var.Text)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `@ObservedObject`?

Comment: It should be `@ObservedObject` instead of `@StateObject`

Answer (score 1):

`@StateObject` isn't designed for a view model object and the `View` struct is actually a view model already so you can just use that. Simply pass in your model struct to a custom `View`'s init, store it in a `let` and `body` is called whenever it changed since last time it was init. You can optimize by only passing in the properties of your model struct the `View` actually uses. To use `ForEach` with bindings it is:

```
ForEach($modelStore.items) { $item in
    TextField("", text: $item.title)
```

`@StateObject` is for when you need a reference type in a `@State`, i.e. to do something with longer lifetime that uses a delegate, closure or a Combine pipeline. Since we have `.task` to automatically manage the lifetime of async/await, nowadays we don't even need `@StateObject`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.

Comment: See code sample